# Cannot access state due to function called in mapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to be able to access a value inside of my state in a specific js file, however the `mapStateToProps` already looks like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = summarySelector;
```

Normally to access a value inside of my state it looks something like so:

```
const mapStateToProps = ({
  sessions,
  consumerName: { value: consumerName },
  consumerEmail: { value: consumerEmail },
  consumerPhonenumber: { value: consumerPhonenumber },
  order,
  event,
  tickets,
  extraItemQuantities,
}) => ({
  consumerName,
  consumerEmail,
  consumerPhonenumber,
  order,
  event,
  tickets,
  extraItemQuantities,
});
```

However in my case the `SummarySelector` is an external function, I tried re structuring it to the following to access my variable (as well as making the smaller changes required):

```
const mapStateToProps = ({
  summarySelector,
  discountedTotal,
}) => ({
  summarySelector,
  discountedTotal
});
```

Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does `summarySelector` needs state as a parameter?

Usually that's the case for redux selectors, so you'll need to pass the state doing something like this:

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  summary: summarySelector(state),
  discountedTotal: state.discountedTotal,
});
```

Keep in mind that mapStateToProps is a function that receives (state, props) as parameters and returns an object with the desired props.

Answer (score 2):

`summarySelector` is a function, giving state as parameter it returns an object.

**To preserve initial structure** in `mapStateToProps` function you need to call `summarySelector` and return object extended with additional property.